# Can't access class method in a seperate method c#, the name item1 does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

Trying to use a class method, with an instance of that class in a separate method. Used method RandomItem() to build instance of class Item. Using ViewItem() to display the item, it says:

```
"The name 'item1' does not exist in this context"
```

This is my code:

```
  class Program
    {
        public class Item
        {
            public string part1;

            public Item(string _part1)
            {
                part1 = _part1;
            }

            public void PrintItem()
            {
                Console.WriteLine(part1);
            }
        }
        public static void Main() 
        {
            RandomItem();
            ViewItem();
        }

        public static void RandomItem() {
            string randomPart1 ="";
            Item item1 = new Item(randomPart1);
        }
        public static void ViewItem() {
            item1.PrintItem(); //this is where the error is "The name 'item1' does not exist in the current context
        }
    }   
}
```

Kind of new to c#, just not sure why I can't access item1.PrintItem(), or if I'm even allowed to do this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I would advise you to google "c# variable scope", there should be a lot of documentation that might be interesting to you.

Comment: You should read about the scope of variables in C#. Your class has no static variable called `item1`, so a static function will not be able to access said nonexistent variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a variable is local, you need to `return` it so the caller can access it. Then you need to pass it as an argument for another method to access it.

```
    public static void Main() 
    {
        var item = RandomItem();   //Retrieve item 
        ViewItem(item);            //Then pass it in
    }

    public static Item RandomItem() {
        string randomPart1 ="";
        Item item1 = new Item(randomPart1);
        return item1;    //Return the item to Main
    }


    public static void ViewItem(Item item1) { //Accept item as argument from Main
        item1.PrintItem(); 
    }
```

There are other options-- for example, you could use a static variable-- but this is the most common way to do it.

Answer (score -2):

You need to declare "item1" outsite of your "RandomItem()" method as a member of your "Program" class.

On a console App the entry point is a static method. So everything you declare in your "Program" class must be static.

```
class Program
{
    public static Item item1; // the static field that contains the instance of your "Item"
    public class Item
    {
        public string part1;

        public Item(string _part1)
        {
            part1 = _part1;
        }

        public void PrintItem()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(part1);
        }
    }
    public static void Main() 
    {
        RandomItem();
        ViewItem();
    }

    public static void RandomItem() {
        string randomPart1 ="";
        item1 = new Item(randomPart1);
    }
    public static void ViewItem() {
        item1.PrintItem();
    }
}
```